# I can't save multiple objects at once Mongoose ExpressJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**When i want to insert orders with a total price on mongodb it shows me like i can't save them, maybe i have to put them as array but i don't know how to do it, please help me**

Order Model:

```
const OrderSchema =  new Schema({
    product: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product',
        required: true
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
    
}, {
    timestamps: true
});


const Order = mongoose.model('Order', OrderSchema);
module.exports = Order
```

Order Controller: this is my function to save an order

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  
   
   
    const orderdetail = new OrderDetail({
        order: req.body.order,
        user: req.body.user,
        product: req.body.product,
        totalprice: req.body.totalprice,
       
    });
    
        orderdetail.save()
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message || "error creating."
            });
        });
    
   
 
});
```

On Postman: here is when I insert records

```
[{
       "order": "5f1c8322ca3b5b0dc1511847" , 
        "user": "5f1c70eed08a0c0bff3bc6b4" , 
        "product": "5f1c6dc6d08a0c0bff3bc6b2",
        "totalprice": "455"
    
},
{
       "order": "5f1c839dca3b5b0dc1511848" , 
        "user": "5f1c70eed08a0c0bff3bc6b4" , 
        "product": "5f1c6dc6d08a0c0bff3bc6b2",
        "totalprice": "455"
  
},
{
       "order": "5f1c8322ca3b5b0dc1511847" , 
        "user": "5f1c70eed08a0c0bff3bc6b4" , 
        "product": "5f1c6dc6d08a0c0bff3bc6b2",
        "totalprice": "455"
      
}]
```

Error:

> "message": "OrderDetail validation failed: order: Path `order` is
> required., user: Path `user` is required., product: Path `product` is
> required., totalprice: Path `totalprice` is required."

Comment: sometimes this kind of error occurred when you forget to install a `body-parser` package did you install `body-parser`?

Comment: @kedarsedai yes i installed it

Comment: you dont have the `totalprice` and `order` fields in your schema. you might want to add them.